# Pandas error "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'add_categories'" when trying to add catorical values?

Tags: python, pandas

I was getting an error earlier 'ValueError: fill value must be in categories' when working with a dataframe. After researching, it appears I need to add categorical options for each value that is a category but I'm getting the below error:

```
  catgoricalValues = ['embarked', 'sex', 'pclass']

  df[catgoricalValues] = df[catgoricalValues].astype('category')
  df[catgoricalValues] = df[catgoricalValues].add_categories(df[catgoricalValues].unique())  # add options for catgorical values


AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'add_categories'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The error occurs because [`pandas.Series.cat.add_categories`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cat.add_categories.html) is a Series method, and `df[['embarked', 'sex', 'pclass']]` is a DataFrame.
- Use [`pd.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html)
- [pandas: Categorical data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html)
- Some of the `titanic` dataset columns contain `NaN`s, which can't be categories.

  - Use `.dropna()` when creating the categories.

#### single column

```py
df['embarked'] = pd.Categorical(df['embarked'], categories=df['embarked'].dropna().unique())
```

#### multiple columns

```py
# looping through the columns
for col in ['embarked', 'sex', 'pclass']:
    df[col] = pd.Categorical(df[col], categories=df[col].dropna().unique())

# alternatively with .apply
df[['embarked', 'sex', 'pclass']] = df[['embarked', 'sex', 'pclass']].apply(lambda x: pd.Categorical(x, x.dropna().unique(), ordered=True))
```

- [Appending new categories](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html#appending-new-categories)

```py
# create a sample series
s = pd.Series(["a", "b", "c", "a"], dtype="category")

# add a category
s = s.cat.add_categories([4])
```

Comment: awesome! Thank you so much!